# Match all words that appear within parenthesis except for certain phrases

Tags: regex

My matching Regex for capturing all words within parenthesis (including the parenthesis) is

`\([\w\s,.]+\)`

I need to ignore the capture when (City of Toronto) appears

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, (Capture This) consectetur adipiscing
>   elit. Integer nulla nisi, viverra ut eros vitae, bibendum elementum
>   quam (City of Toronto). Morbi quam libero, sollicitudin et sapien et,
>   lacinia (Capture this as well) euismod tellus.

I would want the matches to be #1- (Capture This) and #2- (Capture this as well)

Essentially I'd like to create a white list of phrases to avoid but if they don't match, then capture the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that what follows is not `(City of Toronto)`
[`(?!\(City of Toronto\))\([\w\s,.]+\)`](https://regex101.com/r/NThXA9/1)

You can use [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)  `|` to add multiple options.

The slightly faster version from @ctwheels with the alternation:

[`\((?!City of Toronto|Hong Kong|United Kingdom\))[\w\s,.]+\)`](https://regex101.com/r/N5NzjB/1)

Comment: Thank you bird. Here is an example with multple conditions `(?!\(Hong Kong\)|\(United Kingdom\))\([\w\s,.]+\)`

Comment: `\((?!City of Toronto\))[\w\s,.]+\)` performs slightly faster

Comment: @stanek I have updated my answer and used your example from the comment. @ctwheels Thank you! I have added an updated version to my answer placing the `\(` and `\)` outside of the negative lookahead.

Comment: The updated example will miss out on brackets where the search term starts the bracket but other text follows e.g. "(City of Toronto newword)". You can fix by placing the phrases to ignore in brackets followed by the closing bracket `\(`: [`\((?!(City of Toronto|Hong Kong|United Kingdom)\))[\w\s,.]+\)`](https://regex101.com/r/HoW3yS/1)